# Why my progressbar in toplevel window is not moving?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am actually creatng a gui which include searching data.I want to show a loading progress bar (indeterminate) to show results are being loaded .I want this progress bar in a new toplevel window but I tried to place it but it didn't showed at first.So after many research ,I make it to appear on screen but there is a problem with it. It opens the window with progress bar and everything freezes and progressbar doesn't work itself.But window is destroyed on time.I want that progressbar moves so that it looks responsive so that user gets idea that something is going on.I start progress bar just before loading results and then starts loading results which include for loops for 2-3 times then all results are gathered then the toplevel window is completely destroys .
Everything is happening accept the new window is freezing and progressbar is not moving.

I have tried everything I could.

```
class Loading:
    def __init__(self,title):
        self.title = title
        self.window = Toplevel()
        self.window.geometry('350x40+100+100')
        self.window.title(self.title)
        self.window.lift()
        self.window.grab_set()
        self.window.focus()

    def start(self):
        self.pbar = Progressbar(self.window, orient="horizontal",length=300, 
         mode="indeterminate")
        self.pbar.place(x=10,y=5,height = 20,width = 300)
        print('starting loading')
        self.pbar.start()
        self.window.update()

    def stop(self):
        self.window.destroy()
```

I want that my toplevel window display progressbar moving till all rseults are loaded from different files and it gets destroyed after this

Comment: if you run long-running code then it stops `mainloop()` and you should run this code in separated thread or at least use self.window.update() in long-running code to give mainloop time to get events from system and update widgets - so it will not freeze.

Comment: Can you tell me how to put it in a thread as it is a class and If I created itsobject in a thread then how will I call the stop method of this object.

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: this part of code works for me on LInux. I mean to run loading code in thread, not progressbar. In most GUI's widgets can't run in thread because they will have no access to window. Thread could run code which loads data and sends to main thread information that it has to change value in progressbar using `.set()` - [progressbar example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/progressbar)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this snippet of code !

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('100x100')


def progressbar():
    pwin = Toplevel(root)
    pwin.geometry('350x40+100+100')
    pwin.title('Sample progressbar')
    pbar = Progressbar(pwin, orient="horizontal", length=300,
                       mode="indeterminate")
    pbar.place(x=10, y=5, height=20, width=300)
    print('starting loading')
    pbar.start()
    pwin.update()


Button(root, text='PBAR', command=progressbar).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

And then you can use `pwin.destroy()` to destroy the `progressbar` after loading is finished !

Comment: This is working fine as I place this function in thread but without it it doesn't show working as usal and when in thread I am ubale to destroy it as self.pwin doesn't exist even when I created it.